# PPA build fails due to Python.h missing

Tags: python, ppa, packaging

I'm trying to package my application for Ubuntu using PPA. The build fails because it can't find `Python.h` ([build log here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/186457508/buildlog_ubuntu-utopic-i386.python-pyblock_0.52-3_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz)). This library is provided by `libpython2.7-dev` and I have it in build dependencies and according to build log it is installed.

Building using `dpkg-buildpackage` (or just simple installation using `make` and `make install`) works on my current Ubuntu 14.10 clean installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a little mistake in your `debian/control` file where you assumed that the python2.7 package provides the interpreter. `/usr/bin/python` is actually provided by `python-minimal`.

That's why the following lines in your [Makefile](https://launchpad.net/~vojtech.trefny/+archive/ubuntu/blivet-gui/+sourcepub/4454113/+listing-archive-extra) don't work as expected in the build environment:

```
PYVER := $(shell python -c "import sys; print sys.version[0:3]")
CFLAGS := -g -I/usr/include/python$(PYVER) -Wall -Werror -fPIC $(OPTFLAGS) -fno-strict-aliasing
```

`PYVER` is empty as the `python` command is not installed in the ppa sbuild.

To solve your build problem, just use the following `debian/control` file:

```
Source: python-pyblock
Section: python
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Vojtěch Trefný <vtrefny@redhat.com>
X-Python-Version: >= 2.7
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python-all-dev, gettext, libdevmapper-dev, libdmraid-dev
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Homepage: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/pyblock.git/

Package: python-pyblock
Architecture: any
Depends: python2.7, python-selinux, python-parted, ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: Python modules for dealing with block devices
 The pyblock contains Python modules for dealing with block devices.
```

Note that I've only added `python-all-dev` as a build dependency (it depends on both the interpreter and its `-dev` packages)

Comment: Tested ok in my own [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~sylvain-pineau/+archive/ubuntu/sylvain.pineau/+sourcepub/4458806/+listing-archive-extra)

Answer (score 0):

This is pure speculation, but your compile command is:

```
gcc -g -I/usr/include/python -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -fno-strict-aliasing -DUSESELINUX=1 -c -o dm.o dm.c
```

However, `libpython2.7-dev` install files in `/usr/include/python2.7`, according to the [file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/libpython2.7-dev/filelist).

Perhaps you should consider different compile flags. There might be something in your system configuration which lets it use the headers in `/usr/include/python2.7`, even though you include a different directory.